# Velocity time graph analysis: what does a concave downward $v$-$t$ curve mean?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, velocity, differentiation

[image]

This is a screenshot from the lecture about **the analysis of various velocity-time graphs** I was watching.

I understand that

> the **concavity of velocity-time graph** will tell about the
> increasing or decreasing nature of acceleration.

Therefore, this graph must **have decreasing acceleration with time** since the curve is clearly concave downwards.

Then, why it is written "increasing acceleration" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concave or convex it's easier to note the **change** in the gradient of the graph to see how the acceleration changes.
Here the acceleration ( the gradient of the curve) has a low negative ( suppose -1) then it becomes steeper with time so it has a negative value of larger magnitude ( suppose -4). Thus the magnitude of the acceleration *is* **increasing**. Thus you are right as the absolute acceleration is ofcourse decreasing.
Hope I could help.

Comment: Why does the "concavity" reasoning fails?

Comment: Does not fail, edited.

Comment: So, the concavity will only tell about the "magnitude" of increase or decrease of acceleration?

Comment: Yes, correct and the direction if its positive or negative acceleration can be found by seeing the slope of curve.

Comment: Please verify answer if you're satisfied with it.

Comment: Can you please tell how can you tell if its positive or negative acceleration by seeing the slope of the curve. I get it that the slope is decreasing along the curve, but that just tells us that the magnitude is decreasing. Why and how it should tell anything about the direction?

Comment: If the slope points downwards(obtuse angle) acceleration is negative while if it points upwards (acute angle) then acceleration is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is related to acceleration by: $$\vec{a}=\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$$

Think in terms of the slope of the velocity-time graph.

To study acceleration from this graph, you have to see how the slope is varying w.r.t each point.

(This graph does have decreasing acceleration. Only the magnitude increases.)

Comment: Slope is negative since theta is obtuse. Slope only tells us about the increasing or decreasing nature of "velocity", not acceleration. What am I missing?

Comment: The slope of this curve is the acceleration. The slope becomes *more negative* as you go along the graph.

Comment: The increasing or decreasing nature of velocity IS acceleration!